# VB.NET read only some cells for each row from csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I have a csv file that has the following structure :

```
id,name,adress,email,age
1,john,1 str xxxx,john@gmail.com,19
2,mike,2 bd xxxx,mike@gmail.com,21
3,jeana,1 str ssss,jeana@gmail.com,18
.......................
.......................
```

What I would like to do is to read the csv file, skip the first line (contains headers) and extract the 2nd, 3rd and 4th data from each row and populate a datagridview.

This is the code I'm using however it brings me all the csv content :

```
DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "ID"
DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "NAME"
DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "ADRESS"
DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "AGE"
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser _
            (openFile.FileName)//the csv path

                'Specify that reading from a comma-delimited file'
                MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
                Dim currentRow As String()
                While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                    Try
           currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
           With DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow) 'Add new row to data gridview'
                        End With
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using
```

So can someone show me how to do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simple as reading the first line and discard it, Then start to read the real data from your file

```
Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser(openFile.FileName)
   MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
   MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
   Dim currentRow As String()
   ' Read the first line and do nothing with it
   If Not MyReader.EndOfData Then
       currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
   End If
   While Not MyReader.EndOfData
      Try
          ' Read again the file
          currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
          DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow(1), currentRow(2),currentRow(3)) 
      Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
          MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
      End Try
  End While
End Using
```

**EDIT** Seeing your comment below then I have changed the line that add the row to add only the strings at position 1,2 and 3. This of course is different from the columns added to the DataGridView. It is not clear if you want to change these columns to contains only these 3 fields. If you still want the column for ID and AGE in the grid you could change the Add to

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add("", currentRow(1), currentRow(2),currentRow(3), "")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, what about reading that target data in each row : 2nd, 3rd, 4th ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The grid is populated with data or not? Do you mean that you want to read that data from the grid now?

Comment: Hi, Yes the grid is populated with the whole data from the csv, but it's not what I want, I want it to be populated with only "name","adress" and "email" from each row present in the csv file no "id" and no "age"

Comment: All right then, but you need to change the columns in the DataGridView because you include ID and AGE there. However, currentRow is an array of 5 strings where the first string at index 0 is the ID and the last one at index 4 is the AGE, you could add directly the strings at index 1,2,3, see my updated answer

Comment: Hi Sir when i tried your code, it seems that i got an error message.

Comment: @Aljie I am not able to read minds and I do not have a crystal ball to see the screen of your computer :-) , what is the error message?